# поразрядные операции

Tags: c#

Имеется задача :ввести целое число с консоли (0-4000000000), поместить его в переменную типа unsigned int. Вывести на экран его младший бит, старший бит. Хотелось бы узнать каким именно блин образом достучаться до бита если как я вычитал минимальной адресуемой единицей является байт, сидел читал про поразрядные операции и что-то тоже не очень помогло. Писать надо на c#.

Comment: [Поразрядные операции](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.22.php) ?

Comment: `value & 0b1` и `value >> 31`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov у меня вопрос то что сдвиг вправо на 31 позицию это чтобы выцепить старший бит, а там где с логическим множением это чтобы младший бит. И ещё я верно помню что если читаем слева направо то первый бит это старший,а последний это младший?

Comment: и я что-то видно ещё недопонимаю что нам даст если мы сместим старший бит на позицию младшего,как нам всё таки вывести то его?

Comment: @Mark, этот код работает одинаково как на LE, так и на BE машинах, так что про это даже не думайте, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: @Mark, `Console.WriteLine(value >> 31)` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯